# Ext js stateful grid/panels / customer provider

Tags: extjs

I'm trien to setup a stateful grid/panel with ext js 7.3.1 modern like this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cjn

I've added a Customer Provider for debugging but i cant see any read/write of real settings like width or hidden state. When I run it again, it wont save.

Is there something wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't related to the provider. Unfortunately the grid in modern isn't hooked up to support it. To achieve it, you would need to override the internals of the grid and have it save to your storage provider whenever the appropriate changes (width, hidden, etc) occur.

Comment: Are you sure about that? cause its documented here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#cfg-stateful

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The functionality for being able to save/restore state exists at the base component level, however the grid itself doesn't have anything hooked up to do any grid specific things.

Comment: but it's actually also listed in the changelog: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/whats_new/whats_new.html

Comment: Fair enough, but it's not implemented. If you look through the grid source you won't see it do anything around firing events or restoring state.

Comment: well actually i just discovered https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.Panel.html#cfg-statefulDefaults i guess i was using it wrong, when i set stateful "by hand" wo width: true, and hidden: true it's working in the grid columns, i will prepare a fiddle, but I cant get it working for resized panels atm.

Comment: this is working so far for grid but not for the panels resize/collapse: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cjn

Comment: Right but that's not the grid being stateful. In classic all you need to do is set `stateful: true` on the grid. Here, you have to set the statefulness on each column and manually manage it. It also won't handle re-ordering of columns, or moving (via drag drop etc). As I said, there's no holistic solution for the grid, you will need to cobble it together for the basic state parts.

Comment: well its working for grid so far, even with a custom provider with snyc ajax request to sql db, but panels are still not working :(

Comment: Nevermind: it's working for width/height and collapse now, just had to define it on every resizable element on its own